# Error in import lstm fromhttp://mxnet.io/tutorials/python/char_lstm.html

Tags: mxnet

I follow the Character Level LSTM Tutorial on http://mxnet.io/tutorials/python/char_lstm.html.  After run this line
 `

import lstm`

I get the error:

> ImportError: No module named lstm

How to make this work? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial mentioned in the link is currently removed from the page. So, alternatively, you can check its [notebook version here](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet-notebooks/blob/master/python/tutorials/char_lstm.ipynb).

The error you were getting was because your program was not able to find "lstm" module which is defined in lstm.py file. It has LSTM cell implementation and it also has lstm_unroll function which is used later in the program. So, you should have [lstm.py](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet-notebooks/blob/master/python/tutorials/lstm.py) file in the same folder where you are running char_lstm tutorial. This way you won't get this error.